# How to replace the definition of global variable in the target of a makefile?

Tags: makefile

```
COMMON= D_FF       
all :  
        ncverilog $(COMMON).v
test1:     
        COMMON=T_FF  
    ncverilog $(COMMON).v  
test2:  
    COMMON=JK_FF_tb  
    ncverilog $(COMMON).v   
test3:   
    COMMON=JK_FF  
    ncverilog $(COMMON).v
```

I just want to replace the global variable by local variable but it is not working.Like if i called "`make test1`" it is still replacing "`COMMON=D_FF`" only rather than "`COMMON=T_FF`".

Comment: When entering your question, you can use the orange question mark button to get help about formatting. Using the curly brackets button will make your makefile snippet more readable...

Answer (score 4):

The makefile in your question has its formatting all mixed up. It looks like your makefile can be rewritten like this though:

```
COMMON = D_FF
test1 : COMMON = T_FF
test2 : COMMON = JK_FF_tb 
test3 : COMMON = JK_FF

all test1 test2 test3 :
    ncverilog $(COMMON).v
```

Answer (score 0):

`make` is a declarative language and has scoping rules that are almost nothing like programming languages that you're used to.  `COMMON` isn't a "global" so much as there happens to be a (slightly exceptional) way to set target-specific variables (See Reinier's answer).